# Can 2 computers that are behind routers connect to each other without proxy

Tags: sockets, networking, routes

When I do socket programming, I found at least one computer has to have a public IP to make the connection (or reverse connection). I'm wondering if it is possible for  2 computers that are behind different routers to connect to each other (and they don't have port forwarding and don't use proxy)? If that's not possible, how bit torrent works for computers that are behind routers? Does it mean the computers that are behind different routers cannot share among each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bittorent clients are using a protocol named uPNP, that tells router to redirect specified port in bittorrent client to computer that runs client.

Here is more information about protocol.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play

Comment: Thanks, I read it but am a little confused. Does uPNP make the port forwarding automatically as long as the router allows it? Currently, if we want to expose a computer to public, we have to setup the NAT port forwarding manually. So uPNP is just doing something similar to that?

Comment: yes, it makes what do you do by NAT port forwarding by automatically.